# Uncaught TypeError: web3.personal.sign is not a function while using a dapp built using truffle

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask

I'm running Metamask on Chrome.

When I run the following in the developer console on a random page or even Etherdelta Metamask prompts me to sign a message and this is the expected behaviour.

```
web3.personal.sign('0x68656c6c6f', web3.eth.accounts[0], console.log)
```

However, when I try to run the same in the dev console on the basic Dapp created by `$ truffle init webpack` I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: web3.personal.sign is not a function
```

web3.personal does not have a function "sign" but has only `["_requestManager", "newAccount", "unlockAccount", "sendTransaction", "lockAccount", "listAccounts", "getListAccounts"]` on the truffle dapp but has the following on other sites `["_requestManager", "newAccount", "importRawKey", "unlockAccount", "ecRecover", "sign", "sendTransaction", "lockAccount", "listAccounts", "getListAccounts"]`.

Note: `web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.coinbase, '0x68656c6c6f', console.log)` still works though.

Why is this happening?

---

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Create the basic truffle dapp by running the following commands:

   - truffle init webpack
   - truffle compile
   - truffle migrate
   - npm run dev
2. Open http://127.0.0.1:8081 in Chrome
3. Run `web3.personal.sign('0x68656c6c6f', web3.eth.accounts[0], console.log)` in the dev console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Summary**

Use `web3.eth.sign()` instead.

**Why not `web3.personal`?**

Despite `web3.personal` being defined in some implementations, it's not a standard as far as I can tell.

The [v0 web3.js API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) does not list the personal API. Neither does the v1, except for [`web3.eth.personal`](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html), which may be what you want.

I believe Metamask is exposing the non-standard API `web3.personal`. (So is the web3 included in `geth attach`)

**Update: Confirmation from Metamask**

In [response from metamask](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/1839#issuecomment-329594897) to my question, "Which spec did you base `web3.personal` on?"

> **kumavis** commented 15 minutes ago
>
> @carver et al
> geth thread: [ethereum/go-ethereum#2940](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/2940)
> our implementation: https://github.com/metamask/eth-sig-util
> usage examples: https://github.com/flyswatter/js-eth-personal-sign-example

This confirms my suspicion that `web3.personal` isn't a standard. Some clients are copying what other clients did. Which means you can't assume that it will be done the same way everywhere.

**Web3.js v0 vs v1 in Truffle**

Truffle's most recent [release note](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v3.4.6) that mentions web3.js is:

> **v3.4.6** ... Internal: We now use web3 v0.20.1 inside Truffle

So you'll have to make due with the v0 web3.js implementation of `web3.eth.sign` until they update to v1. V1 is still in beta, so it may not happen right away.